# Python 2.7. Read one file using enumerate to get line numbers and go to another file using line numbers

Tags: python, parsing, line

Here are two files which I want to read only one of them.

```
        a1                  b1
        a 1 line            b 1 line                
        a 2 line            b 2 line
        a 3 line            b 3 line
        a 4 line            b 4 line
        a 5 line            b 5 line
        a 6 line            b 6 line
        ...                   ...
        a 400 line          b 400 line
```

what I want to do is read only 'a1' file and if statements are true, keep the line_numbers. And then go to b1 file through the line_number. 
And do something.
(I don't want to read 'b1' file and the files are nearly the same. Actually a1 file and b1 file is pretty big. so I don't think using readlines or anything would be good for this)

so far, what I have done is

```
with open("a1") as fin1, open("b1") as fin2:
    for num1, line1 in enumerate(fin1,1):
        if '77' in line1:
            for num2, line2 in enumerate(fin2,1):
                if num2 == num1:
                    print line2
```

output

```
b 77 line
```

desired output

```
b 77 line
b 177 line
b 277 line
b 377 line
```

It seems like it just excuted the 2nd for statement once, and went on a vacation. any help? 
Thank you very much in advance. 
(Sorry if my English bothers you.)

Comment: No. I wish it was homework. Related to work. I simplified the code. cowokers use Java. I am the only one using Python.

Comment: Looks like you already got your answer, but just in case you were still wondering about the original behavior: your `fin2` file descriptor reaches the end of the file during the first for loop. Subsequent for loops over `fin2` start at the end of the file and so you'll need to `fin2.seek(0)` before the for loop.

Comment: Thank you very much for the comment. I was worndering about what had happend to the two for loops.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`itertools.izip`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/itertools.html?highlight=itertools.izip#itertools.izip) can efficiently iterate two iterable items, pairing them up.  You won't even need the line numbers:

```
import itertools

with open("a1") as fin1, open("b1") as fin2:
    for line1, line2 in itertools.izip(fin1, fin2):
        if '77' in line1:
            print line2
```

If the two files have differing numbers of lines `izip` will stop at the shorter file.  Use [`itertools.izip_longest`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/itertools.html?highlight=itertools.izip#itertools.izip_longest) to provide a fill value and continue to the end of the longer file.